# Post binary data to Microsoft face api and return 400 bad request

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I have converted an image into byte array and try to post it through Microsoft face API, but I have been receiving Http400 bad request. I am not sure if this problem is caused by the headers or binary data I created.  I did manage to post an image uri to it in similar manners and it works just fine.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("content-type", "application/octet-stream");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", 
                                "MY-KEY");
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/face/v1.0/detect");
request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
return response;
```

This is the request and for some reason the content-type is not there. Could some one help to explain?

> {Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://eastus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect', Version: 2.0, Content: System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent, Headers:{  Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: MY-Key  Content-Length: 141600}}

This is the API reference [Documentation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236).